# URL Validation using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url, apex

I'm using the following regular expression.

```
regForUrl =/^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)(?:(www+\.)?)(?:([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.))+([a-z]{2,3}\/)+(?:[\w\-\.\_\__\~\:\/\?\#\@\!\$\,\;\*\$\(\)\&\=\+\:\%]?)+$/;
```

Example URL = 'http://test.domainName.com.ab:5445/endUrl'.

This regex not accepting the above mentioned URL. If ":" occurs the regex returning false. Please solve this issue...

Comment: You are not matching the port `:5445`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: Might want to use a tool like https://regex101.com/ to test your code more easily

Comment: Have a look at [RFC 3987](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3987.html)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)(?:(www+.)?)(?:([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.))+([a-z]{2,3})+(?:[\w-._~:/?#@!$,;*$()&=+:%]?)$
```

But I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this.

Comment: Why all these useless capture groups? What is the purpose of `([a-z]{2,3})+` in your regex, that doesn't make sense? Why the last non capture group for only 1 character? `www+` matches `wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww` (not an error but ?)

Comment: @Toto, you are right. I saw these and other... weird expressions. I just limited to fix the original regex. That's why I said "I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this".

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$
```

**This holds good for all these** (example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), http://example.com, https://example.com & any parameters as well).

Comment: What about `ftp` protocol? Why a capture group for single `s`? Your regex matches `.......` or `-.~~!`, not sure these are valid URL. Have look at [RFC 3987](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3987.html)